# Hibernate count, sum etc

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, netbeans

Using Hibernate/SQL Server,

Let's say that I have entity A, with compomnent entities Aa, Ab etc. which have fields x,y,z.

```
Query queryResult = s.createQuery("from A");
java.util.List A;
selectedA = queryResult.list();
```

I can easily get the count of a sub-entity using

```
int countAa = A.getAas().size();
```

But how could I do something with conditions like for example

```
int count = A.getAas() "where x = 2"
```

or

```
int count = A."get sum of Abs.y"
```

Should I make a new query each time or is there another way ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Criteria with Projections will solve your problem. Check [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-projection) for documentation

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write like this:

```
Query queryResult = s.createQuery("select sum(abs(y)) from A");
```

- abs(y) is a mysql function, so check DB manuals if you use another DB engine

or
    Query queryResult = s.createQuery("select count(*) from A where x = 2");

You can also use "group by" and "having". More details here http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-grouping